What does a feature's integrated gradient actually represent in the context of a regression task?
I've been reading about IGs, but all the articles I've read describe it in terms of a classification task. And in that context it makes a little more sense to me as the change in probability for a certain class. But in a regression context, I have no feel for its interpretation. Does a positive response mean that it influences the final regression value up, and a negative response influences the final value down?

can you post some references to what you are saying?
